# How to set a proxy to run cypress in Github Actions?

Tags: github, cypress, github-actions

I have a proxy to set it on my Visual Studio by this command line on the terminal : `export HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:22548`. I can run my script without issues. But I can not put this config on GitHub Actions?
Somme one can help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solve this by adding this code on my main.yml file

```
jobs:
 cypress-ua-run:
   name: Cypress UA test
   runs-on: [ self-hosted, Companyname ]
   timeout-minutes: 20
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run cypress in github actions, you'll probably want to use the action they provide. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions#Basic-Setup

EDIT: see this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#about-environment-variables

you can set an environment variable at the workflow, job or steps level

```yaml
jobs:
  cypress_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "run cypress test"
        run: echo $HTTP_PROXY
        env:
          HTTP_PROXY: http://127.0.0.1:22548
```

Comment: There is no response to my question